# How to understand the boolean expression in lambda expression?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

In the textbook, this is the expression of "True": λxy.x, so what's that mean? (do I need to replace x or y?). And the "IFELSE" expression: λfxy.fxy, I have no idea what is f and how to understand this expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the textbook is describing [Church Booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans). They are one of the possible encodings of the values `true` and `false`.

If you are confused about what `λ x y. x` means - this is simply a shorthand for `λ x. λ y. x`. Here's what happens when you apply the booleans to some variables:

```
true a b = (λ x. λ y. x) a b = (λ y. a) b = a
false a b = (λ x. λ y. y) a b = (λ y. y) b = b
```

So, basically, `true` is encoded as a lambda taking two parameters and selecting the first one, and `false` selects the second one.

As for why `ifelse` is defined like that, it helps to look at its intended usage:

```
ifelse true a b = (λ f. λ x. λ y. f x y) (λ x'. λ y'. x') a b =
= (λ x. λ y. (λ x'. λ y'. x') x y) a b = (λ y. (λ x'. λ y'. x') a y) b =
= (λ x'. λ y'. x') a b = ... = a
```

Similarly, `ifelse false a b = b`. So, the `f` in its definition is supposed to be substituted with either `true` or `false`.

Notice also how `ifelse` does not actually do anything interesting. It does not have to, because the booleans are already defined in such a way that `ifelse c x y` is equivalent to just `c x y`. (a concept related to this observation is *eta-reduction*, I believe your textbook mentions this somewhere)